# How can I convert an IEnumerable<MyType> into a MyList<MyType>?

Tags: c#

I have a custom List `MyList` that is an extension of `List`, and I have an IEnumerable (or IQueryable) which I want to do `.ToList()` on, but I guess, `.ToMyList()`.

How can I implement the ToList() method? The source code for ToList() is to create a new List() and pass in the IEnumerable as a parameter, but I am not sure what it does with it.

Comment: It enumerates it and ads elements to the list.

Comment: How you create MyList, does it has any `add` method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your class subclasses `List<T>`, and you [provide the correct constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx), you should be able to do:

```
MyList<MyType> list = new MyList<MyType>(theEnumerable);
```

If you want a simple extension method, similar to `Enumerable.ToList`, you could write your own:

```
public static MyList<T> ToMyList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> theEnumerable)
{
    return new MyList<T>(theEnumerable);
}
```

You could then call this via:

```
var list = theEnumerable.ToMyList();
```

Note that subclassing `List<T>`, in general, is really not a very good idea.  You should really consider subclassing [`Collection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and implementing `IList<T>`, if you need a custom collection, instead.  You can still provide the same constructors and use the methods above to populate the custom collection, if required.

Comment: *"If your class subclasses `List<T>`"* -- and let's hope that's not the case, since deriving from `List<T>` is a terrible idea.

Comment: @cdhowie Yeah, I completely agree - but, the OP stated "List MyList that is an extension of List", which suggests that's what's being done.

Comment: @cdhowie I just edited to address that it's really not a good approach to do that, too.

Comment: My brain is totally fried and my question is probably wrong, my list is actually extending BindingList<T>. I don't understand your answer and what to put as the constructor either. You seem to have shown a use-case for the solution, but not the solution itself?

Comment: @ReedCopsey Thanks, now I feel comfortable upvoting. :)

Comment: @SLC You could always just make a constructor that adds all of the elements into your collection, and use that as above.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a base class and you are able to delegate list population to its constructor, do that:

```
public MyList(IEnumerable<MyType> items) : base(items) { }
```

Otherwise, this constructor should work for almost any collection class:

```
public MyList(IEnumerable<MyType> items)
{
    if (items == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("items");

    foreach (var item in items)
        Add(item);
}
```

Then you can write an extension method, or call this constructor directly to populate a new list from a sequence.